# Method that makes action bar comes up again when hidden

Tags: android, button, android-actionbar, android-notification-bar

I'm devolopping a tablet app. I want it to work full screen. After days of investigeting on google, I achived it using:

```
.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_MODE_OVERLAY);
```

The Tablet I'm using is 4.1 Android version. That was working perfectly though I had to made some changes like doing my own action bar (because sistem action bar made navigation buttons comes up) and dialogs.

Now the problem is that I've installed my application on 4.2 Android version and it's a disaster. Each time I touch the screen, navigation buttons comes up. It's really annoying. This is driving me mad, I've tried many things but it's still coming up.

Is there a way to solve this problem? I think if I could override the method that makes navigation buttons comes up I could achieve my objective. Anybody know which is this method??

It is not working in 4.0 Android version neither. That doesn't bother me much, but if you know a way to solve it as well, that would help me a lot.

I would appreciate any help. Thanxs a lot.

Answer (score 1):

> Each time I touch the screen, navigation buttons comes up.

One of the core Android concepts is that the user is *always* in control of the UI. If developers were allowed to create fullscreen Apps and override the navigation buttons, it would be trivial for an App (rogue or otherwise) to create a screen which the user could not get out from.

If you really want to remove the system bar, you will system-level access or you need to build your own custom Android.